# Minimization method when function calls are expensive and hysteretic?

Tags: python, scipy, minimization

I have a laser pointer mounted on a motorized piezo stage that can tip and tilt it. The laser needs to hit a photodiode and I'd like to write some Python code for automating the alignment of the motors to get the highest signal at the photodiode.

The problem is that the motor movement is slow (more than 50 iterations would be prohibitively long), not perfectly repeatable (piezomotors tend to "slip"), and not perfectly orthogonal (i.e. can't independently optimize one motor at a time).

So, my problem is maximizing a function $f(m_1,m_2,m_3)$, where $f$ is the photodiode signal measured at motor positions $m_1,m_2,m_3$ - with the complication that the function may depend on the motor position history.

I know there are entire libraries in scipy for minimization, but they seemed geared towards applications where data is immutable (function always gives the same answer) and function calls are rather cheap. What are some good approaches for iterative optimization in my case?

My first attempt was to scan each motor and fit a peak to the scan and move there. Since the motors are not independent, I had to manually do this iteratively going through each motor. This is a slow process that I'd like to automate without the curve fitting process

Comment: This sounds more like a Kalman filter (tracking) problem than a function minimization problem.

Comment: Thanks! Do you know of  a "Kalman Filter" minimizer function? I usually think of KF as tools for tracking but haven't used them for active  optimization personally

Comment: My thought is that even if the target is not moving, you treat it as if it were (since over time the ideal motor positions will probably drift due to temperature, wind, whatever, anyway) and track it rather than just do a one-time minimization.

Comment: If you are for some reason *required* to treat it as a minimization problem, then something like gradient descent with numerically approximated gradients may be appropriate.

Comment: Good thoughts. In my case the position is stable over the course of a day, so I was inclined towards one time optimization.

Comment: Are there gradient methods you know of that don't get confused by noisy/hysteretic function calls like in my case?

Comment: I have some ideas about how I'd start experimenting, but no "sure thing" solution. The motor slip is going to kill you when you try to make small adjustments to get a gradient estimate. So maybe something related to the simplex method, where you start with a locus of points that you know surrounds the solution, and then shrink that boundary progressively.

Answer (score 0):

It seems this exact use case is solved with the sci-kit optimize package (https://scikit-optimize.github.io/stable/getting_started.html). This package is built around optimizing a noisy function that is expensive to call, which matches well with my project needs.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).